# How does os.getuid() and os.path.isfile work

Tags: python

I am reading about the os module and was wondering how `os.getuid()` and `os.path.isfile()` works I have tested this in `python 2.7` and `os.getuid` returns the `UID` of the current running user which is my username when I run id, however, does this work?

Comment: It asks the kernel?  I’m not sure I see what you want to know.

Comment: I mean what commands does it use

Comment: It uses system calls like [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) and (unsurprisingly) [`getuid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getuid.html).  Python provides such functions precisely because they cannot be implemented independently.

Comment: I see however what do you mean by implemented independently?

Comment: No (pure) Python program can be written that obtains its UID without calling `os.getuid` (or starting another process that asks the question).

Comment: Alright so a Python program can use getuid() or something else without the need to call os.getuid therefore getting UID can be implemented independently from os.getuid? or am i not understanding

Comment: That’s the opposite of what I said.  (Perhaps you read “No” as “No,”?)